# How do I defeat ProviderIncompatibleException?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

This seems to be related to the common misconfiguration issue of EF not connecting to SQL Server databases when using code-first or local db instances.  However, my scenario does not include either of those.  I'm trying to run a production application containing 34 projects, freshly pulled from SVN, that connects to a couple different remote SQL boxes.  When I debug I get this exception thrown at what seems to be the first attempt to access the main db:

`ProviderIncompatibleException`
`The Provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.`
Inner exception:
`Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\\MACHINE-NAME$'.`

Stack trace:

```
    at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ObjectContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()
   at XX.Service.Base.GenericRepository`1.Get(String predicate, Object[] values, Int32 PageNumber, Int32 PageSize, List`1 SortColumns, String[] path) in [...]
   at XX.Service.Base.GenericRepository`1.Get(SearchCommand cmd, String[] path) in [...]
```

Fails on this line:
`ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext;`

My connection string:
`<add name="ProdContext" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER.companydomain.com\XX,51332;Initial Catalog=ProdDB;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

I've looked at every SO question listed in a search for "providerincompatibleexception login failed" yet the answer still eludes me.  I **can** log on to the SQL server with SSMS using Windows Authentication.  The DBA says I am in the same access group as the other application developers.  I have fiddled endlessly with directory permissions and authentication settings in my local IIS Manager.  When debugging if I inspect the underlying Context, the server address and connection string are correct.

I have to be missing a configuration setting somewhere.  I **can** use the application on the production site, but not from my local VS2012 build.  What else can I check?  What am I missing?  I was hoping to be able to get a successful build and get somewhat up to speed before the rest of the devs return from their holiday vacations...

Comment: I have no idea how to solve the problem, but I hope intense warfare is involved :)

Comment: What version of ef? Ef6 migrated to a dbconfiguration setup witha provider assignment through the ef namespace. Regardless can you post your `<entityFramemork>` config section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is more to do with the inner exception than the outer:

`Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\\MACHINE-NAME$'`

I would guess you are using Local IIS Web Server and not the Visual Studio Development Server.

I believe The Identity of the Application Pool is what affects this.  Either that or the account that the ASP.NET/IIS service is running under.

IIS Manager->Application Pools->Right click the pool your application runs under->Advanced Settings->Identity

I believe that is the account that will be used for SQL Server when you are using an integrated security connection string.

Compare that setting to other developer's machines.

Additionally, under IIS Manager->Sites->Click your site->Basic Settings, there is a "Connect as" option.  Usually this inherits if you have nested sites, but on one occasion I had to set this explicitly on a nested site to resolve issues with the wrong user being passed for authentication.

Comment: Today another developer verified that I needed to explicitly enter my login info for the app pool identity instead of using any of the default identities.  This solved the problem.